# Is iOS UIWebView based on Safari implementations like Android WebView on Chromium?

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I'm searching now for a while but I've not found a solid statement on an apple developer site about the underlying implementation of the UIWebView.

Does anybody know that?

Comment: not obviously programming related -- i Mean .. not relevant for SO

Comment: and I don't think so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple introduced `WKWebView` in iOS8. This implementation replaces UIWebView and brings with it the same javascript engine that Safari on iOS uses. The old UIWebView was not as responsive as Safari as it had an older implementation of the javascript engine and leaked memory.

There is a great article on NSHipster about it, http://nshipster.com/wkwebkit/

Comment: Okay, thank you for the answer. Do you know if the underlying browser engine is the same as iOS Safari is using?